# Как работает exception translation в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, repository

Всем привет!

Изучаю Spring и в документации сказано, что все исключения класса @Repository будут автоматически транслироваться в DataAccessException.

**Repository для User:**

```
package org.example.dao;

public interface UserDAO {
    void addUser(User user);
}

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public void addUser(User user) {
        throw new HibernateException("unchecked exception");
    }
}
```

**Service для User:**

```
package org.example.services;

public interface UserService {
    void addUser(User user);
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        try {
            userDAO.addUser(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**В web.xml:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

На деле я получаю HibernateException. Не понимаю, как работает трансляция исключений. Почему HibernateException не транслировался в исключение типа DataAccessException?

Кто подскажет, что я понял не так? :)

Comment: Ну возможно потому, что `DataAccessException` находится ниже `HibernateException`, а вы тем делом ловите именно `Exception` - при этом явным образом указываете ошибку `HibernateException`.

Comment: @And, что-то я не совсем понимаю. А в чем тогда смысл трансляции? Насколько я понял, Spring должен исключения из Repository транслировать в какое-то исключение иерархии DataAccessException. Видимо, понял неправильно. Не подскажете, как это работает на самом деле?

Comment: Попробуйте ловить `DataAccessException`.

Comment: @And, а как я поймаю DataAccessException, если HibernateException находится вообще в другой иерархии? Exception поймает любое (в т.ч. и транслируемое) исключение.

Кажется мы не поняли друг друга. Мой вопрос в том, что HibernateException не транслируется в исключение иерархии DataAccessException. И я не могу понять, как это работает.

Comment: Код показывает: `HibernateException` extends `RuntimeException`. и  `DataAccessException` extends `NestedRuntimeException`, а уже `NestedRuntimeException` extends `RuntimeException`, ну а `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`.

Comment: @And, все верно. Это означает, что я не могу поймать `DataAccessException`, если бросаю `HibernateException`. Минимальный суперкласс - `RuntimeException`. Но в этой ситуации это не так важно. Если вы знаете ответ, прошу вас написать его. Если же нет - давайте не будем флудить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что я упустил главную деталь: указать в конфигах реализацию трянслятора исключений `org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator`.

**Summary:**

1. Сконфигурировать транслятор исключений `org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslator`
2. Пометить класс `@Repository`
3. Не ловить исключения в самом DAO.

Всем спасибо!